# Error when trying execute statement with where from joined table in subquery

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get rank of spent hours from my table in amount of time. It works. But now I want to restrict it to one usergroup. So i made this:

```
SELECT
    s.shortname AS servername, s.displaycolor AS displaycolor,
    MIN(
        if(`yearweek`=yearweek(CURRENT_DATE(),3) AND (s.admin_group=u.usergroupid OR find_in_set(s.admin_group, u.membergroupids)>0),
            (SELECT COUNT(*)
            FROM godziny_tygodnie AS x
                LEFT JOIN vbulletin.vb_user AS xu ON xu.userid=x.dbid
            WHERE gw.sid=x.sid
            AND x.`yearweek`=gw.`yearweek` AND x.`time` > gw.`time`)+1
            AND ( xu.usergroupid=s.admin_group OR find_in_set(s.admin_group, xu.membergroupids)>0)
        , NULL)
    ) AS rweek0,
    -- there are more columns simillar to previous, but with different time interval
FROM godziny_tygodnie gw
    INNER JOIN godziny_miesiace gm ON gw.dbid=gm.dbid AND gw.sid=gm.sid
    INNER JOIN godziny_lacznie gt ON gw.dbid=gt.dbid AND gw.sid=gt.sid
    LEFT JOIN serwery AS s ON s.id=gw.sid
    LEFT JOIN vbulletin.vb_user u ON u.userid=gw.dbid
WHERE gw.dbid=:uid
GROUP BY gw.dbid, gw.sid
```

And it gives me error `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'xu.usergroupid' in 'field list'`

Why it can't be executed? `vbulletin.vb_user.usergroupid` exists...

Comment: But pgc_vbulletin.vb_user is what's aliased as xu. Does that table have a usergroupid column?

Comment: I believe you have the parenthesis in the wrong place. The first AND line ends with )+1, which left the next AND not part of the SELECT.

Comment: pgc_vbulletin is the same as vbulletin, i've corrected that :) Hmm that parenthesis is the answer i think :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was with wrong parenthesis. The `)+1` from end of 9. line should be on the end of 10 line. Now everything works :)